# Can I setup a specific login action for each module?

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony1, module

I'm working on a symfony 1.4 project which contains a frontend and a backend. I want to know if it's possible to configure a different login action for each module.

I've tried to add a settings.yml file in the config folder of each module but it doesn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there can be a settings.yml file per module.
You could try to forward to the correct login action by analysing the "module" parameter of the request in a base login action.

Comment: I also think @greg0ire's suggestion is the way forward. Depending on what you want the separated login to achieve, you could pass an additional parameter with it to the single login point and then deliver a "signin success" URL accordingly, and execute any other needed stuff.